# Can MySQL show the respective timestamps in each INSERT output message?

Tags: mysql, configuration, mysql-8.0

For example, after an INSERT, I see:

> `Query OK, 296 rows affected (0.02 sec)` 
>   `Records: 296  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0`

I would like to see timestamps with these lines, if possible, e.g.:

> `2019-02-15 12:00:00.000 - Query OK, 296 rows affected (0.02 sec)` 
>   `2019-02-15 12:00:00.020 - Records: 296  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0`

Can I configure MySQL to do this?

Comment: No, but your own client code in a particular scripting language could. There are also script helping programs that can prepend timestamps to arbitary output. Can you describe the context more for a more general answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html

This is close to what you wanted:

```
mysql> prompt \D  \R:\m:\s >
PROMPT set to '\D  \R:\m:\s >'
Sat Feb 16 02:10:47 2019  02:10:47 >SELECT NOW(6);
+----------------------------+
| NOW(6)                     |
+----------------------------+
| 2019-02-16 02:10:59.885525 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
Sat Feb 16 02:10:59 2019  02:10:59 >
```

But, alas, it does not do all of what you want:

```
Fri Feb 15 18:13:49 2019  18:13:49 >INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('asdf');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

Fri Feb 15 18:14:04 2019  18:14:04 >
```